# CSS responsive design left column % right column px

Tags: css

I'm building a page with a layout of 1160px and it was split to left & right column.

It's important that the right column will always be 307px width even when resizing the browser while the left column should grow and shrink according to the screen size.

How do I achieve that ?

```
                                 1160px
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| |-------------------------------------------|  |-------------------|  |
| |                                           |  |                   |  |
| | Need to be calc in css 1160px-307px-gutter|  |        307px      |  |
| | can we do it with %?                      |  |                   |  |
| |-------------------------------------------|  |-------------------|  |                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should post the code you've tried already.

Comment: `Need to be calc in css` then use `calc()` like so: `calc(100% - 307px - gutter)`. And of course there are alternatives.

Comment: @HashemQolami, I want it to be done in css (scss) not in js

Comment: @Alon [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) *is* a part of CSS. It is introduced by [CSS Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#calc-notation).

Comment: Relevant - [browser support for calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) (IE 9 with some issues and IE10+)

Comment: @misterManSam, will that work on ie9 ? or not, what's are the issues?

Comment: @HashemQolami, Thanks, width: calc(100% - 1.75% - 307px); worked

Comment: @Alon - From my source: `IE9 appears to ignore calc() expressions when display:table is used.` Apart from that, you're golden.

Comment: @misterManSam, thx, I'm not using display:table. But, do I need to do -webkit-calc(), -moz-calc(), etc... ?

Comment: @Alon - I would argue that it is not needed. The unprefixed version is compatible with all widely used browsers and IE9+. It couldn't hurt to place the prefixed versions above the unprefixed property. Use [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for a rundown of common browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use : `calc();`

```css
#content{
 position:relative;
 max-width:1160px;
 height:300px;
 background:red;
}
#left{
 width: -webkit-calc(100% - 307px);
 height:200px;
 background:green;
}

/*if not supported 'calc', you use*/
/*#left{
    position:absolute;
 height:200px;
 background:green;
    left:0;right:307px;
}*/
#right{
 position:absolute;
 width:307px;
 height:200px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 right:0;top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to do width calc for all vendors ?

Comment: @Alon - I would argue that it is not needed. The unprefixed version is compatible with all widely used browsers and IE9+. It couldn't hurt to place the prefixed versions above the unprefixed property.

Comment: I just wrote another solution :) => `left:0;right:307px;`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cjsjLub3/

`box-sizing:border-box;` will allow you to tell the left `div` to have a 100% width and any padding will be included inside that 100% overall width.

NOTE: You may not want to use the *, but I copied these few lines along with their respective comments from code that I regularly use (_s theme) so you can look at the research if you like.

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements; see http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Not needed for modern webkit but still used by Blackberry Browser 7.0; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; /* Still needed for Firefox 28; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}   
#content {
    height:600px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    top:0px;
}
#left {
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    padding:0 307px 0 0;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;

    background:#ff0000;

}
    #right {
    height:100%;

    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 307px;

    background:#0000ff;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
    oijhr o;gihr ogehrgoi ehro;giehr oiehr oiehrgo ierho gihrog ihrog ihroig horig heori ghoepi hoih poerih goperihg opeirhg opeiurhg poeirhg poeirhg poeirhg eorihg oeirhg poeirhg;eobgnreoigheor igjh orig oerihg oerihg oerigh o;erihg oerih opir hgoeirh gorpih goperih goperih o
    </div>
    <div id="right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty cleanly using CSS3 flexbox:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.Layout {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.Layout-left {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.Layout-gutter {
  width: 40px;
}

.Layout-right {
  width: 307px;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Layout-left">
    100% - 40px - 307px
  </div>
  <div class="Layout-gutter">
    40px
  </div>
  <div class="Layout-right">307px</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions so far are using `calc`, `float`, `flex-box` or other properties which I think are over-complicating the issue. You can simply use CSS Tables to give you the layout you require with the minimum of code and the maximum cross browser support.

Check out this [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4pL47ny/) or the snippet below.

```css
html, body {margin:0; background-color:#eee;}
.bounds {display:table; width:100%; max-width:1160px; margin:20px auto; background-color:white;}
.bounds .left, .bounds .right {display:table-cell;}
.bounds .right {width:307px; background-color:#eebbff;}
.bounds .content {padding:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="bounds">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="content">left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="content">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```